# free webgis environment solution?

Tags: open-source-gis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Steps to Start Web Mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/steps-to-start-web-mapping)

soon I will be trusted to develop a webgis system. This project will take an advantage of a currently developed business system. The business system is using pure PHP, Java and MySQL. The project plan is to embedded a mapping system so the management will be able to see all the report tables (from the business system) and when they click on some "numbers" they can view the map as well. I guess it's a standard nowadays.

What I'm hoping to get answer is what free webgis environment that you are suggesting to accomplished this? I'm not new in webgis but I'm not following the recently updated information about this webgis environment. Mostly I'm using desktop GIS.

Comment: Without further information about your requirements, we'll only be able to provide general info about webmapping which was already collected in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/steps-to-start-web-mapping