# Installing QGIS for Viewing purpose only and not edit?

Tags: qgis

I would like to find out if it is possible to install QGIS to be able to view and query data but not be able to make edits,is this possible.Can someone please advice how to do this.

Comment: I asked a similar question some time ago.  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57741/what-is-the-best-free-web-gis-browser

Comment: By query do you mean just get info on features? Or view stuff like the attribute table?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [QGIS Browser](https://www.qgis.org/en/site/about/features.html#qgis-browser).  Although this doesn't allow you to open a project (I don't think).  It does allow you to view data and list the attributes.  It is rather limited though and does not seem to support searching either.

An alternative would be to put your data into something like [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) or serve it as WMS and in that way you could have standard database user account control to allow some users to edit the data and some only to view it.  This moves the control from QGIS to the database.

[QGIS Webserver](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial) (and provide QGIS Web Client to your users instead of QGIS desktop) could provide a simple solution so you can create your project in QGIS desktop and serve it as-seen as WMS.  Geoserver can do the same but you can have the flexibility of user accounts too.

Comment: You can also have a try with shapefiles by making them read-only and taking ownership for another account so that your users can't change the rights with their accounts.