# QGIS to web map plugin

Tags: qgis, web-mapping

Is there a QGIS plugin that will allow me to embed an interactive web map on a website that requires limited coding? If so, what plugin(s) would be useful for this? I do not need to use open source layers. I already have all of the data.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour.  Most "best" questions are going to run into the restriction on *opinion-based* questions; you can read more about this on the [Don't Ask](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)  page.

Comment: Very related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57741/seeking-free-web-gis-browser

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The plugin you're looking for is called (creatively) qgis2web.
It's on [github](https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web), but you don't want to download it from there.
It's in the standard QGIS plugin repository.
It'll take your QGIS project and output code which you can copy and paste right into a web page.
I've used it a couple of times for simple maps and it works great.  I don't know how well it would work on major complicated projects.

Comment: Thank you. I already had the plug in. It took some time, but I found it. I want to host the data on my computer, possibly as cached data. I also want the map to be on a website I have already created, rather than on another web service.

Comment: Jwells: That's pretty much exactly what that plugin does.  I'm not an expert, but I'd guess that qgis2web is about as point and click as you're going to get for a custom web map, at least this side of ESRI.  Good Luck!

Comment: Tom Chadwin - Just having a little fun.  Your plugin is awesome!  Thank you for building it.