# Converting from SLD to Carto CSS?

Tags: sld, tilemill, cartocss

I have a bunch of layers and corresponding SLD's running a WMS service. I was exploring the possibility of shifting to a TileMill's tile based TMS service.

For this, I would like if it were possible to convert the SLD to CartoCSS, and then start the styling from that point on in tilemill.

Is there a SLD to Carto CSS?

I have seen the question [Are there tools to directly import QGIS projects into Tilemill?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/41262/are-there-tools-to-directly-import-qgis-projects-into-tilemill), but the answers there really do not answer my question.

It's almost 2016, and Mapbox has renamed their old product as Mapbox Studio Classic.  However, I'm still looking for a way to convert SLDs to CSS, so that we can convert old SLDs to CSS for conversion projects.

Comment: Are there any findings from your side on this matter? What did you end up using?

Comment: @gcarrillo: We ended up writing the CartoCSS from scratch. It didn't take that long, and our designer was more happy writing the CSS, than he ever was fiddling around with the XML.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as there is no solution to this problem.

Comment: @iant: Closing a question, because there is no answer feels totally incorrect. This question could be answered by something as simple as 'Currently there is no way of doing this' Just closing this does not seem contribute in anyway.

Comment: we're trying to cut down on the unanswered question count, there is currently no good answer but feel free to add your answer and accept it and I'll reopen

Comment: closing questions which do not have an answer just to bump down the un-answered metric is pointless at best, and disingenuous at worst.

Comment: Showing that there is an interest in a problem might push some to develop an answer as well. This question is plus 14, which isn't bad. There is definitely interest and that interest could generate an answer. I, for one would be helped greatly if an answer were found to this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about CartoCSS with has reached EOL https://www.mapbox.com/blog/the-end-of-cartocss/

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question, because CartoCSS has basically become obsolete: https://www.mapbox.com/blog/the-end-of-cartocss/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its asker has requested that it be closed.