# Simple WebMapping application with postgis Database

Tags: openlayers-2, web-mapping, java, geotools

am very new to web-mapping, so this question may be a little misguided.

I want to develop a simple web mapping application using OpenLayers  which can display Cadastral information that are currently in PostGIS(2 tables: property and boundaries).

I want this to be as simple (and as low maintainence) as possible:
-Use java for developping
-The user can search a parcel by 4 fields (name, indice complement and nature) existing in table : "titre"
-and then the user can generate the an A4 sheet for print that contains the title/property plan and also a table containing the name, X and Y of boundaries of title/property from the second table : "Boundaries"
-Styling of the vector layers is of minimal importance.

PS: i tried to use the library geotools with applets but i have a problem with versions, because the tuto that i used is old 2004, and i couldn't find the old version 2.1 on the net, i only have 2.7

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [geoserver](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) for serving server side data. You create a store in geoserver for POSTGIS or any other database.
2. Since you are using java you could probably use JSF or any other framework or neither. Just setup TOMCAT or whatever server(or may be you could deploy geoserver and your application in same server) and write simple html pages(**depends on point 4**).
3. Take a look a openlayers [example](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/) which makes it possible to render your data to web page. Also take a look at opengeo [workshop](http://workshops.opengeo.org/openlayers-intro/)
4. For any feature search you could either write you **custom code** (select from postgis) or you could you wfs **getFeature** request and display it in your map.

Here is what wonderful @iant have done **http://ian01.geog.psu.edu/geoserver_docs/apps/gaz/index.html**

**For printing :**

1. You can use [geoExt](http://geoext.org/examples.html#print-your-map)

Comment: if i get well your point the solution is to use in the client side : GeoEXT(openLayers + ExtJs) and the server client with Geoserver ?? 
While searching on the net i found a server called Geomajas is it better than geoserver ?

Comment: @Asma.O try this http://apps.geomajas.org/showcase/. Geomajas is different beast. I haven't tried it but you can check it on http://files.geomajas.org/maven/trunk/geomajas/docbook-gettingstarted/html/master.html#section-about-this-project. It's a framework. For your requirement the mentioned technology stack will sure be more than enough ;)

Comment: yes i already take a look on the documentation, but i think geoserver have a large community  of developpers, so it's a plus for me in order to do this as fast as possible (i don't have much time, only 3 weeks)

Comment: @Asma.O don't worry in three weeks you will rock. Also have a look at iant's tutorial it's what you will be making.

Comment: yes i like what iant's did, it's a great job, i guess i'll do the same. if am not mistaking he uses GeoEXT(+extJs)+ OpenLayers +Geoserver

Comment: @Asma.O yes :) ! Best of luck.