# What are some use cases for GeoServer?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I am new to GIS area and am having trouble understanding what GeoServer is. Even after reading their site and the wiki page I am struggling to understand its usage. What does it mean by -- "allows users to share, process and edit geospatial data". Who am I sharing with? What am I sharing? Am I opening up a rest interface to query Geospatial data? If so why not call it a web server? Also if that is the case can I think of this GeoServer as an app server? What are some practical use cases for this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  However, as it stands I think your question is far too broad for our focussed Q&A format.  As mentioned in our [Tour](http://gis.stackexchange.com/tour) we encourage people to post just their most important question first and then to research/ask any others separately.

Comment: Ha! That is the most pointed question I can ask as I know nothing as you can see. Can you not let the community decide on at least newbie/ignorant questions? I cannot do research without getting my head around what its used for isn't it?

Comment: "Does GeoServer open up REST interface to query geospatial data?" does not seem to hard to ask as a single focussed question before zero-ing in on any unanswered aspects that remain from what would have been your multi-part question.

Comment: When I started with Geoserver, I just set an instance up on my desktop Pc and started playing with it. It has lots of demo data and after that, you can ask specific and focused questions. Just by setting it up, you will answer a lot of your own questions anyway ..

Comment: Thanks! That's a great suggestion. I have been reading up more on other sites I found and am just about forming some ideas. I was primarily hoping to be shown some URLs by posting here. Surprisingly learning about stuff is not something stackoverflow tolerates or encourages.

Comment: Please do not discount the focussed Q&A that the Stack Exchange network provides as an alternative, and I think highly effective, learning style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially it publishes mapping web services from a spatial store. So you're kind of right, in that it's a web server, but one which is specifically designed for spatial data and spatial services - such as **[WMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Service)**.

From there you can include these services in applications you build or in desktop applications where supported (pretty much all of the good ones).

For more learning this is a really good question:

**[How to start web mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping)**

Comment: Wow! Thanks. That URL you pointed to is something I have been trying to find all weekend.