# GIS with UI options? Creating a Map based WebApp fast

Tags: web-mapping

I want to build a WebApp which is basically a map with points of interest, filters, and a list of those points. Something really similar to AirBnB, or any other map based app.

[image: Map based application]

Of course, I could just take Google Maps API and build what's around. But I guess a lot of people already did that, and may be I could use their work to make mine faster. Here's what I need :

- Adding multiples POI
- A list of POI that are showed on the map
- A way to filter POI
- Most have a behavior to handle a lot of POI
- Have to work on desktop, mobile and tablet

I already know one template that can do nearly all of this, it is call [Bootleaf](https://github.com/bmcbride/bootleaf). But before programming, I would like to know if you know other tools that might work better.

*Disclaimer : this is a copy/paste from this [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/254170/building-a-map-based-webapp-fast) on Programmers, which the community didn't feel it was the right place. I hope GIS SE better suit it.*

Comment: If you want to build an app fast use an existing API like Google Maps. There are other APIs, some even have templates but they can cost quite a lot! The amount of effort you intend to put in is inversely proportional to the cost of setup - there's no free lunches here.

Comment: Yep, I know how to use Google Maps API, but you still need to create the entire WebApp around it. BootLeaf is a free solution that does implement some of the features I listed. But I wanted to know if there is other solutions. I not looking for free only solution.

Comment: The QGIS android API is a good place to start looking, if that doesn't meet your requirements you can try the ArcGis for Android API but they will probably want to integrate you with ArcGis Server.

Comment: Thanks. But if it's Android only, it won't work as I want to create a WebApp, not an Android App.

Comment: Sorry, that's way outside my area of experience. I have only looked into Android applications to suit existing Android equipment in the field. There are many good APIs for creating a map in a web page but I can't comment on them.

Comment: I do not want to sound condescending but, just as a double-check, have you had a chance to review http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping

Comment: I saw that one, but it's totally different, as he's asking for a tool to make a map with stats by city. I don't need such features, what I need is more what around the map.