# Creating web site for people to input their locations and other info?

Tags: geoserver, web-mapping, open-source-gis, boundless-suite

I am new to open source Web GIS and have done some self training about the basics of Geoserver, PostGIS and Openlayers. Right now I am in a rush to set up a web site for up to 100 people to access it internally and input their locations and name, etc.  When they open the sites, they should be able to find their location, click on it to create a point and in the pop-up window to input their basic information. I saw a similar site a long time ago.

I know how to overlay a point layer with Google or Bin, but how can I make it editable?

Are there any source codes I can refer to?

This will be a small project for an event and I plan to host it on a spare window box I have.I have installed the OpenGeo Suite 4.1.1 but I am also open to other sources that can help get the job done easily.

Comment: I recently posted in another forum links to different API's and their samples.  You really need to decide what platform you want to build on.  You can view that post here:  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping/120550#120550  Once you have a platform decided on, edit your question and add a tag for the API you are using.  You'll have much better luck getting assistance.

Comment: Thank you. I have added some info to the end of my post. This is not a long term thing.

Comment: OpenGeo suite should suit you if the app does not need to be very beautiful. You must create a new table to PostGIS for the data, publish it as WFS with GeoServer and use GeoEditor for editing.