# How to use shapefile in QGIS on Debian?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, installation, debian

I am extremely new to GIS and I just received a shapefile, as a zip file that includes the following files:

```
filename.SHX
filename.SHP
filename.prj
filename.dbf
filename.cpg
```

but I am not sure how I would display this data.

Is there anything else needed?

I just installed QGIS on a Debian box, but I guess it won't run, because it's just CLI, with no display environment.

Comment: I install xorg-dev on Ubuntu, then ensure my ssh client enables X-forwarding, then qgis will start. I don't use Debian but it will have a similar way.

Comment: i just installed the xorg-dev, but when i try to run qgis i get the following error: QGIS starting in non-interactive mode not supported.
You are seeing this message most likely because you have no DISPLAY environment variable set.

Comment: Sorry I gave you bad infro, got reader an dexplorer mixed up http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer-desktop use qgis You need explorer

Comment: Does your ssh client allow X-forwarding? It's the -X argument to ssh, or some setting on the interface, or as it states the configuration of your client DISPLAY.

Comment: I think this question would be better focussed on "How to get QGIS running under Debian?" because until you have that or some other GIS software running that can display shapefiles the shapefiles will be of no use to you.

Comment: @BradHazelnut What do mean under Debian box? Have you installed a Debian distro on your own machine without GUI, or are you using a distant server via `ssh`? This question is good, but not GIS related. If you can reformulate it, you should ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 3):

Yes this is a standard GIS shapefile. A shapefile is a bit of a misnomer as it contains between 3 and up to 10 parts.  You have all the correct parts.

You can install QGIS on ubuntu easy enough https://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html

It works on linux or windows, once installed you need to add a vector layer..

Use the this to add your data [image: screenshot]

To just view the data [Explorer](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/explorer-desktop) is an alternate and works on windows

Comment: You can even drag and drop the .shp file (not the others) into the Layers field (at least on Windows).

Comment: @AndreJ. Ooh, cool, didn't know that one. Drag n Drop works on Ubuntu with QGIS 2.6 also, I can confirm.

Comment: ArcReader works on Linux. Yee gads, what blasphemy is this.

Comment: ok once i have this loaded, what i am ultimately trying to do is display this in a php page, i'm not sure if its even possible to do that, since this seems to be like a desktop app, and not sure if i can make it displayable on the web

Comment: John Barca - ho ho, just quoting what "the man" says http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcreader/download

Comment: Brad ask another question or search the stack, web gis questions that list all web methods to display files has been asked many (many) times.

Comment: ok will do, thanks John, also i just downloaded the reader and tried to load those files that i mentioned above and it just keeps giving me the following error: The dropped file did not load correctly, for every file that i am trying to load.

Comment: use the add data button and just add the .shp

Comment: i don't have that option, at least in the version im using 10.2.2 arcreader

Comment: it seems to only have an option to open a pmf file, which i don't have

Comment: I screwed up I listed reader but meant explorer answer updated, just use qgis

Comment: Brad, to display this on a web page is a whole world of pain over and above just viewing its contents. There is a community post on 'how to start with web mapping' http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping which will set you on the right path to including your shapes on a php page.