# Seeking database that identifies adjacent postal addresses and/or zoning of postal address?

Tags: data, spatial-database, address

Can someone point to:

1. a database that identifies adjacent postal addresses (for example, if I provide an address, the database provides address of houses on either side of house address)?
2. a database that lists zoning of addresses, so as to distinguish commercial, house, and apartment buildings?

I realize it's unlikely I'll get either of this data apart form large urban centers.

This is for a web app, and my target would be major US cities. I usually use a php-javascript stack, but I can also work with python. I would prefer a free database with api access over other options, but I'm open. The idea of the web app would be to collect user addresses and then compare those addresses (say to identify a neighbor).

Comment: Please specify what software you are wanting to use this in (javascript web-app, ArcGIS Desktop, ...). Also, may help get better answers if you specify the scope of your target area.  What I mean is, are you trying to get addresses for a particular community, region, country, world-wide? Ex: Most local governments in the US maintain their own GIS files for address points and zoning info (where zoning is used), even if this is done by contract with state/region in some areas.  This may be very accurate, but unrealistic to use if you're trying to cover the whole country or world.

Comment: The database by itself is static, i.e. it just holds a bucket of data, it's up to the GIS software to make these sorts of decisions based on the data within the database. Firstly do you have any data with street addresses, postcodes and zoning? Secondly what software are you using/prepared to acquire? Thirdly what programming experience/languages do you have?

Comment: @John I am using javascript-web app type setup. I am most interested in large US cities, but suburban and rural US areas would be interesting too. No need for other countries' data

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I am not prepared to pay for any databases or software, but I'm open to any programming languages, api's, etc.

Comment: I would recommend PostGIS on PostgreSQL as the database, there's a valuable post for beginners http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping, as for the data, I have no idea about free U.S. data but OpenStreetMap http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=5/51.500/-0.100 is a good place to start (for roads etc..). It is possible that some datasets are available for download but that is worthy of a new question (or questions as the answer changes by LGA/state).