# How to generate maps like some at Wikipedia?

Tags: cartography, india

I've absolutely no idea if this is a proper forum to ask this or not. But I know that I can at least get some information here.

I was reading few wiki articles on Indian rivers and I'm very much impressed by the maps on those pages. Example:

[image]

[image]

Maps in the school geography textbook that I'm reading are dull & boring. Example:

[image]

These maps got me excited. I want to generate few maps like these. I specifically want to add details of the second map in to first map, for all the rivers shown in the first map. I also want to add names of reservoirs & dams with icons etc.

The guys who made these maps have also made lot of such maps for wiki:

http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:NordNordWest/Gallery/Maps
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Shannon1/Maps

How can I generate such maps?

I'm an absolute newbie. I just discovered this.

Don't we have an advanced version of this tool? mapsofindia.com/editable-maps/customise-your-map.html where we can just select what we want to include in the map by using checkboxes

Comment: What resources do you have? Do you have a machine where you can install software? Do you have Linux? Do you have knowledge of CSS and could apply that to a different situation? There are a lot of different tools, and it depends on what you are likely to be able to work with.

Comment: Machine: Yes. Linux: can install. CSS: Have bit of web designing experience. So yes.

Comment: Another example: http://www.mapsofindia.com/maps/india/india-rivers-map.jpg

Comment: This looks like a possible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping so I'm thinking a review of that should enable a more focussed question to emerge.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like [Natural Earth Data](http://www.naturalearthdata.com) being used, however as far as creating a map, there are a lot of different aspects that need to go into the process. You need to consider the scope, audience, styling, interactivity, etc.

If you need these maps quickly for a project you might be working on, I would suggest hiring a professional, but by the way you worded your question, it seems like you just want to get into map making in general. If that's the case, here are a few resources I can point you towards.

I would start by reading [How Maps Work](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/157230040X) by Dr. Alan M. MacEachren from Penn State. He is a very well respected individual in the cartographic world and his book is highly informative. It was one of the ones I was told to read when I first started as well. I'd also look into [Thematic Cartography and Geovisualization](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0132298341) by Terry Slocum and others. This is a great starter textbook and is used in many intro to cartography courses.

If you want something with more of an interactive flare to it, I highly recommend  [Web Cartography: Map Design for Interactive and Mobile Devices](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1439876223) by Dr. Ian Muehlenhaus. I read this book in preparation for a mobile cartography seminar I took while getting my Masters degree in Cartography and it was very informative.

Finally, to get your feet wet in the discipline, I'd consider taking a Massive Online Open Course (MOOC). There is one that is taught called [Maps and the Geospatial Revolution](https://www.coursera.org/course/maps) by Dr. Anthony Robinson from Penn State that goes through the background and basics of Cartography. I think if you want to get started making maps, this would be your best place to start.