# Easy way to map & share some spreadsheet points on a web map

Tags: web-mapping

What is an easy solution for placing some points on a web map and sharing the map and info with others from a spreadsheet I have?  I want to be able to change the spreadsheet info and have the map reflect the changes.

The area of interest is Vietnam.  I have been able to export the points to a Google Earth file and maybe that is the easiest solution.

Comment: If you haven't seen this question, take a look: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping
My personal suggestion would be to use Google Fusion Tables, simply for the ease of use.

Answer (score 3):

I think this tutorial of mine is what you're looking for. How To Make a Web Map from a List of Addresses in a Spreadsheet:

http://mangomap.com/blog/post/74368997570/how-to-make-a-web-map-from-a-list-of-addresses-in

Answer (score 1):

[Google Maps can take an address within a Google Spreadsheet to show locations visually on a map with custom labels](http://www.webchick.net/node/132). No geocoding is explicitly required.

[Google Fusion Tables can also turn a table of locations into a map](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/184641)