# Integrating ArcGIS Desktop and web map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, web-mapping

I have some data that has been mapped in ArcGIS Desktop.

I would like to develop something like if I add/change some parameters a new map can be derived so that it can be used for predicting as well.

All this need be done online.

I need this because mine is a health based project and I want it to be made available for public use.

At least I would like to know how it can be published online.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Your question is very broad which is why a duplicate was easy to find.  I think this is the answer on that duplicate that I would recommend reading: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/120550

Comment: Assuming you have a server enterprise database with ArcGIS server and ArcGIS online system setup and running?

Answer (score 0):

I have been using [OpenGeo Suite](http://boundlessgeo.com/solutions/opengeo-suite/) to publish maps online.

It is a geospatial platform for managing data and building maps and applications across web browsers, desktops, and mobile devices.