# GetLegendGraphic request in my Geoserver map code?

Tags: geoserver

I created a map in Geoserver by adding shapefiles as stores and them grouping them as a layer group. I understand that I can use GetLegendGraphic request to make a legend in the map and the user can switch the layers on and off.

I was reading this link http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/get_legend_graphic/legendgraphic.html

and I was wondering where in my code this would go:
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=topp:states&legend_options=fontName:Times%20New%20Roman;fontAntiAliasing:true;fontColor:0x000033;fontSize:14;bgColor:0xFFFFEE;dpi:180

I was also wondering how I would be able to call on the layers in the code.

This is my HTML code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
        .ol-zoom {
          top: 52px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options {
          z-index: 1000;
          background: rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
          border-radius: 4px;
          padding: 2px;
          position: absolute;
          left: 8px;
          top: 8px;
        }
        #updateFilterButton, #resetFilterButton {
          height: 22px;
          width: 22px;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none !important;
          line-height: 22px;
          margin: 1px;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-weight: bold !important;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white !important;
          padding: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a {
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.5);
          color: white;
          display: block;
          font-family: 'Lucida Grande',Verdana,Geneva,Lucida,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
          font-size: 19px;
          font-weight: bold;
          height: 22px;
          line-height: 11px;
          margin: 1px;
          padding: 0;
          text-align: center;
          text-decoration: none;
          width: 22px;
          border-radius: 2px;
        }
        .ol-toggle-options a:hover {
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none;
          background: rgba(0,60,136,0.7);
        }
        body {
            font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-size: small;
        }
        iframe {
            width: 100%;
            height: 250px;
            border: none;
        }
        /* Toolbar styles */
        #toolbar {
            position: relative;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        #toolbar ul li {
            float: left;
            padding-right: 1em;
            padding-bottom: 0.5em;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a {
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: smaller;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: black;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
        #toolbar ul li a:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
        #toolbar ul li * {
            vertical-align: middle;
        }
        #map {
            clear: both;
            position: relative;
            width: 752px;
            height: 768px;
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        #wrapper {
            width: 752px;
        }
        #location {
            float: right;
        }
        /* Styles used by the default GetFeatureInfo output, added to make IE happy */
        table.featureInfo, table.featureInfo td, table.featureInfo th {
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-size: 90%;
            padding: .2em .1em;
        }
        table.featureInfo th {
            padding: .2em .2em;
            font-weight: bold;
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo td {
            background: #fff;
        }
        table.featureInfo tr.odd td {
            background: #eee;
        }
        table.featureInfo caption {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 100%;
            font-weight: bold;
            padding: .2em .2em;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/openlayers3/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>OpenLayers map preview</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="javascript.js" defer></script>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.3.0/build/ol.js" defer></script>
    <script src="ol3-layerswitcher.js" defer></script>
    <script src="layerswitcher.js" defer></script>

    <div id="toolbar" style="display: none;">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>WMS version:</a>
          <select id="wmsVersionSelector" onchange="setWMSVersion(value)">
            <option value="1.1.1">1.1.1</option>
            <option value="1.3.0">1.3.0</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Tiling:</a>
          <select id="tilingModeSelector" onchange="setTileMode(value)">
            <option value="untiled">Single tile</option>
            <option value="tiled">Tiled</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Antialias:</a>
          <select id="antialiasSelector" onchange="setAntialiasMode(value)">
            <option value="full">Full</option>
            <option value="text">Text only</option>
            <option value="none">Disabled</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Format:</a>
          <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setImageFormat(value)">
            <option value="image/png">PNG 24bit</option>
            <option value="image/png8">PNG 8bit</option>
            <option value="image/gif">GIF</option>
            <option id="jpeg" value="image/jpeg">JPEG</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Styles:</a>
          <select id="imageFormatSelector" onchange="setStyle(value)">
            <option value="">Default</option>
          </select>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a>Width/Height:</a>
          <select id="widthSelector" onchange="setWidth(value)">
             <!--
             These values come from a statistics of the viewable area given a certain screen area
             (but have been adapted a litte, simplified numbers, added some resolutions for wide screen)
             You can find them here: http://www.evolt.org/article/Real_World_Browser_Size_Stats_Part_II/20/2297/
             --><option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="600">600</option>
                <option value="750">750</option>
                <option value="950">950</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
                <option value="1200">1200</option>
                <option value="1400">1400</option>
                <option value="1600">1600</option>
                <option value="1900">1900</option>
            </select>
            <select id="heigthSelector" onchange="setHeight(value)">
                <option value="auto">Auto</option>
                <option value="300">300</option>
                <option value="400">400</option>
                <option value="500">500</option>
                <option value="600">600</option>
                <option value="700">700</option>
                <option value="800">800</option>
                <option value="900">900</option>
                <option value="1000">1000</option>
            </select>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a>Filter:</a>
              <select id="filterType">
                  <option value="cql">CQL</option>
                  <option value="ogc">OGC</option>
                  <option value="fid">FeatureID</option>
              </select>
              <input type="text" size="80" id="filter"/>
              <a id="updateFilterButton" href="#" onClick="updateFilter()" title="Apply filter">Apply</a>
              <a id="resetFilterButton" href="#" onClick="resetFilter()" title="Reset filter">Reset</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    <div id="map">
      <div class="ol-toggle-options ol-unselectable"><a title="Toggle options toolbar" onClick="toggleControlPanel()" href="#toggle">...</a></div>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="location"></div>
        <div id="scale">
    </div>
    <div id="nodelist">
        <em>Click on the map to get feature info</em>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
  var pureCoverage = false;
  // if this is just a coverage or a group of them, disable a few items,
  // and default to jpeg format
  var format = 'image/png';
  var bounds = [-3594302.422745372, 4299979.83984952,
                1326460.2317970337, 9321046.312807199];
  if (pureCoverage) {
    document.getElementById('filterType').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('filter').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('antialiasSelector').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('updateFilterButton').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('resetFilterButton').disabled = true;
    document.getElementById('jpeg').selected = true;
    format = "image/jpeg";
  }

  var mousePositionControl = new ol.control.MousePosition({
    className: 'custom-mouse-position',
    target: document.getElementById('location'),
    coordinateFormat: ol.coordinate.createStringXY(5),
    undefinedHTML: '&nbsp;'
  });
  var untiled = new ol.layer.Image({
    source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
      ratio: 1,
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Marine/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format,
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',  
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'Marine:Marine',
      }
    })
  });
  var tiled = new ol.layer.Tile({
    visible: false,
    source: new ol.source.TileWMS({
      url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Marine/wms',
      params: {'FORMAT': format, 
               'VERSION': '1.1.1',
               tiled: true,
            STYLES: '',
            LAYERS: 'Marine:Marine',
      }
    })
  });
  var projection = new ol.proj.Projection({
      code: 'EPSG:3857',
      units: 'm',
      axisOrientation: 'neu'
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attribution: false
    }).extend([mousePositionControl]),
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      untiled,
      tiled
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
       projection: projection
    })
  });
  map.getView().on('change:resolution', function(evt) {
    var resolution = evt.target.get('resolution');
    var units = map.getView().getProjection().getUnits();
    var dpi = 25.4 / 0.28;
    var mpu = ol.proj.METERS_PER_UNIT[units];
    var scale = resolution * mpu * 39.37 * dpi;
    if (scale >= 9500 && scale <= 950000) {
      scale = Math.round(scale / 1000) + "K";
    } else if (scale >= 950000) {
      scale = Math.round(scale / 1000000) + "M";
    } else {
      scale = Math.round(scale);
    }
    document.getElementById('scale').innerHTML = "Scale = 1 : " + scale;
  });
  map.getView().fit(bounds, map.getSize());
  map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
    document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = "Loading... please wait...";
    var view = map.getView();
    var viewResolution = view.getResolution();
    var source = untiled.get('visible') ? untiled.getSource() : tiled.getSource();
    var url = source.getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
      evt.coordinate, viewResolution, view.getProjection(),
      {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html', 'FEATURE_COUNT': 50});
    if (url) {
      document.getElementById('nodelist').innerHTML = '<iframe seamless src="' + url + '"></iframe>';
    }
  });

  // sets the chosen WMS version
  function setWMSVersion(wmsVersion) {
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      lyr.getSource().updateParams({'VERSION': wmsVersion});
    });
  }

  // Tiling mode, can be 'tiled' or 'untiled'
  function setTileMode(tilingMode) {
    if (tilingMode == 'tiled') {
      untiled.set('visible', false);
      tiled.set('visible', true);
    } else {
      tiled.set('visible', false);
      untiled.set('visible', true);
    }
  }

  function setAntialiasMode(mode) {
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      lyr.getSource().updateParams({'FORMAT_OPTIONS': 'antialias:' + mode});
    });
  }

  // changes the current tile format
  function setImageFormat(mime) {
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      lyr.getSource().updateParams({'FORMAT': mime});
    });
  }

  function setStyle(style){
    map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
      lyr.getSource().updateParams({'STYLES': style});
    });
  }

  function setWidth(size){
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    var wrapper = document.getElementById('wrapper');

    if (size == "auto") {
      // reset back to the default value
      mapDiv.style.width = null;
      wrapper.style.width = null;
    }
    else {
      mapDiv.style.width = size + "px";
      wrapper.style.width = size + "px";
    }
    // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
    map.updateSize();
  }

  function setHeight(size){
    var mapDiv = document.getElementById('map');
    if (size == "auto") {
      // reset back to the default value
      mapDiv.style.height = null;
    }
    else {
      mapDiv.style.height = size + "px";
    }
    // notify OL that we changed the size of the map div
    map.updateSize();
  }

  function updateFilter(){
    if (pureCoverage) {
      return;
    }
    var filterType = document.getElementById('filterType').value;
    var filter = document.getElementById('filter').value;
    // by default, reset all filters
    var filterParams = {
      'FILTER': null,
      'CQL_FILTER': null,
      'FEATUREID': null
    };
    if (filter.replace(/^\s\s*/, '').replace(/\s\s*$/, '') != "") {
      if (filterType == "cql") {
        filterParams["CQL_FILTER"] = filter;
      }
      if (filterType == "ogc") {
        filterParams["FILTER"] = filter;
      }
      if (filterType == "fid")
        filterParams["FEATUREID"] = filter;
      }
      // merge the new filter definitions
      map.getLayers().forEach(function(lyr) {
        lyr.getSource().updateParams(filterParams);
      });
    }

    function resetFilter() {
      if (pureCoverage) {
        return;
      }
      document.getElementById('filter').value = "";
      updateFilter();
    }

    // shows/hide the control panel
    function toggleControlPanel(){
      var toolbar = document.getElementById("toolbar");
      if (toolbar.style.display == "none") {
        toolbar.style.display = "block";
      }
      else {
        toolbar.style.display = "none";
      }
      map.updateSize()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The GetLegendGraphic request returns an image (in the format requested) so you can add it to your html where ever you want the legend to appear using an `<img src="..." />` tag as you would any other image you are including in your page.

As for your other question may be looking at the answers to [How to Start Web Mapping?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping) and other [web-mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-mapping?sort=frequent&pageSize=30) questions on http://gis.stackexchange.com may help you.

Comment: I see. I do not want an image of the legend. I want the user to be able to toggle between the different layers.

Comment: Then you need a layer switcher

Comment: I have got a layer switcher and would like to add a categorized legend on there for my WMS layer. I made a call in my js like  var Karibib_Land_Parcels = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS (
        "Land Parcels",
        "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Karibib/wms",
  {layers:"Karibib:Karibib_Land_Parcels",transparent: true, EPSG:4326, format: "image/gif"},
        {visibility: false},
  {legendPath:"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=20&HEIGHT=20&LAYER=Karibib:Karibib_Land_Parcels"},
        {'displayInLayerSwitcher':true}
);

Comment: That does not work, no categorized legend on my layer switcher, am I missing something?