# How to create (online / svg) map with rivers highlighted and without borders?

Tags: tools, web

I want to create a world map on a website without administrative items such as borders, labels and without roads, only the continent outlines, but with big rivers visible (not like in Google Maps, where rivers aren't visible if I zoom out to view the whole world). Some kind of background like a relief map would also be great. What's the best way to do this? I thought about using OSM data – but with which framework / library / editor?

Answer (score 1):

For your data I suspect you can manage with the [NaturalEarth](http://naturalearthdata.com) data set. It contains a rivers set for the whole world with enhanced sets available for the USA and Europe. It also provides a set of raster images based on land use and shaded relief to use as background maps.

As for the best way to get started with web mapping see this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping).