# All coordinates with an specific distance to one point

Tags: openstreetmap, features, reverse-geocoding

I'm sorry for my english!
I have to get the following informations:
I have a specific point with long/lat.
Then i draw a circle with a specific radius (e.g. 5km).
The intersections of all roads on the line of the circle must be displayed as a point.

My idea with photoshop:

[image: circle]

I'm not a real coder, but a mathematician...

So I had the idea to calculate all coordinates, which have the specific radius (e.g. 5km) on the first step. The second step is to check, if the point is on a road. If the point is on a road, I save it in an array. If the point isn't on a road, I delete the point for the session. The third step is to display all points of the array on a map.

That first step works. The distance between the points on the line of the circle are about 0,5m. That is an acceptable tolerance. I get a list of coordinates with PHP. E.g. with 1km radius:

- B 32.0179859432° L 20.999880002°
- B 32.0179846637° L 20.9997800137°
- B 32.0179825847° L 20.9996800441°
- B 32.0179797064° L 20.9995801021°
- B 32.0179760289° L 20.9994801966°
- B 32.0179715527° L 20.9993803363°
- B 32.0179662781° L 20.9992805303°
- B 32.0179602056° L 20.9991807874°
- B 32.0179533358° L 20.9990811164°
- ...

But that are to many results depending on the distance.
1km: 6663 points
10km: 66630 points
...

That are to many points. I can't use a reverse geocoding service to check, if every point is on a road. That would be about 60000 requests in one query. I believe, that only 0,1 % of the points are on a road, so my solution is not very efficient.

Do you habe any idea to solve my problem??
Maybe with frameworks like openlayers, or ...?
Or API's, which can display all coordinates with an specific distance to one point?

Comment: postgis can use ST_Intersect with the circle and return just the intersection points.

Comment: Here is the real time example http://www.geocodezip.com/v2_marcelo_driveTimePolygon.html

Comment: There are an infinite number of points on a line so I wouldn't recommend doing it that way. Your first challenge is to create a circle buffer of 5km from a point in geographic; If you're trying to do the maths yourself you're doing it the *hard* way - Mapperz has a good idea, but start with projecting the point to UTM (choose zone) then buffer to a circle and intersect with the roads - much easier and only a few lines of code.

Comment: Thank you very much Mapperz and Michael Miles-Stimson! The real time example doesn't really solve my problem. Maybe I explained it wrong. I only want the points, which touching the line of the circle. Not the points, which are inside the circle. And then the informations about the points (name and type of road)

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson I know, that is my task an not yours, but can you explain me, how i have to "start with projecting the point to UTM (choose zone) then buffer to a circle and intersect with the roads"? It sounds very great.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is choose an API - in the API the hard work is all done as functions. I use arcpy mostly (and others) but as this sounds like a web application that would not suit, Mapperz has suggested PostGIS (on PostgreSQL, free/open source) and there are other interfaces out there from free to **very** expensive. Once you've decided on an API and language (scripting/programming language, not meaning spoken) then someone will be able to be more specific but probably not I, as I don't do web interfaces - I'm more backend.

Comment: Most of your questions and frustrations can be alleviated if you read http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping many APIs' are discussed although it's by no means a comprehensive list of the options that are available.

Comment: @Mapperz your example isn't really that, what I mean.  The example shows points, which are inside the circle. I need the points, which are hitting the boundary of the circle.

Comment: The Example just needs tweaking to set the intersection to the buffer (circle) like Michael mentions you need to choose the API you require to do this, this going outside the scope of this community.