# Openlayers 3 + JAVA server

Tags: openlayers, mapserver, mapguide

I am new to GIS and I need some help with the architecture of a new system.
The UI will be written using javascript with openlayers 3.

The server should be written in JAVA and as I understand, it can't hold the maps on it's own (too complicated), but has to query and update some kind of a maps server. I'd like some help choosing the right maps server.

A friend recommended mapguide - but I see it's mapguide4j is too complicated and it uses Play framework - We want to use Spring.
Or maybe I didn't get that correctly?

Comment: Please have a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping and feel free to come back with more specific questions

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you might want to look at [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) and or [GeoTools](http://www.geotools.org/), for the server and combine it with [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/) and [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) to hold your data.