# How to create a web-based GIS that can be queried by multiple users?

Tags: geoserver, shapefile, web-mapping, query, basemap

As part of my position, we're required to randomly select townships in our state, select forest, wetland, or grasslands and then throw random points into those habitats to create site for plant and bird samples.  We've created shapefiles and points in R, but what we'd like to do is create a web-based GIS where any user (with the appropriate security clearance) can select a township, display points and polygons in that township, and the random points contained therein, and generate a map that they can print and take out to the field with them, or share with other workers.

Our base layers would be comprised of roads, land use/ land cover, cities/towns, section lines, etc. and then add our custom layers.  We number each township (1-1765), then give them random ranks for each habitat.  Users would need to select "Habitat Type", "Rank", and "Township" and maybe some other criteria, which would then the GIS would zoom into the township that you selected.

In the past we've done this in a piecemeal fashion where one of us would generate individual maps from a local machine in ArcGIS, but it's pretty ponderous and just having one person do it disrupts workflow.  We'd like to get this set up so that each person could generate custom maps from their own work station (regardless of where that work station is located).

I've looked into GeoServer a little, but I was hoping for a little guidance on good places to start the process.  We're not complete noobs, but as scientists (and not web developers), this is a little out of our comfort zone.

Comment: This question is a little too broad I think, and has probably been answered.  Simply put you can use software such as GeoServer, ArcGIS Server, MapServer, deegree to provide the data as some sort of web service (WMS/WFS,WCS...) which can be consumed in any number of clients (QGIS, ArcMap...), not just web clients.  Then you might create a web page using some sort of JavaScript libraries such as OpenLayers or Leaflet, or ArcGIS javascript API... to consume these services.

Comment: It's broad because of where we're starting from.  A lot of the answered questions out there are very specific and we're just not there yet.  Once we get a better direction we'll start to pull from established threads and ask more specific questions that haven't been asked yet.

Comment: @T.Rye That's fine, but helping you get from where you are now to that point isn't really what this site is for. There are quite a few questions on the site about starting out with web GIS, this one has some good info in it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping. I'd suggest looking at esri's training site as well: https://www.esri.com/training/. Another option is to just hire someone to build it for you, if you only need it for this one task it may not be worth your time to DIY.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to go about this, all of which will require your time and effort in learning about the different components. It's certainly doable. Here are some resources, of all types, I would suggest you look into:

[Esri Get started with maps](http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/get-started/get-started-with-maps.htm)

[A Web Mapping Tutorial for Beginners](https://www.gislounge.com/a-web-mapping-tutorial-for-beginners/)

[QGIS - Web Mapping with QGIS2Web](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/web_mapping_with_qgis2web.html)

[Boundless Workshops](http://workshops.boundlessgeo.com/)

Note: Learn by doing examples. Good Luck

Answer (score 2):

With your background and it sounds like you have ArcGIS Desktop I think [ArcGIS Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html) would be the easiest learning curve for creating a webmap for this feature/map interaction (querying and printing).  You also may be able to streamline some current workflows printing and sharing maps since these apps would be web based and device friendly.

Comment: I considered ArcGIS online, but we're a kind of shoestring operation and we'd like to work towards an open source direction (aka free or cheaper) if possible.

Comment: If you have many ArcGIS Desktop licenses you should have credits that you can use on ArcGIS Online.  Using GeoServer as your GIS server and Leaflet or OpenLayers as the web client are good options on the open source front, however you will have to spend much more time configuring the services and web clients for the functionality you are desiring.