# Heron mapping client - CGI proxying

Tags: heron-mapping-client

I have downloaded the heron mc and placed in my local C Drive and tried running some of the example maps. But all of the templates that use getfeatureinfo (getfeatureinfopanel, etc) return no features found. By doing some research I think the issue is I need to setup a proxy in Apache and in the proxy.cgi file. However I am not clear on how to do this, nothing I am trying is working or allowing the maps to bring up the features.

Comment: Is there a tutorial on how to do this?

Comment: are you accessing the files through your browser and apache or through explorer? the 2nd won't work

Comment: Also, I'm not committed to using Heron mc and open to a similar application. I am a total novice at programming and the coding aspect is beating down my efforts.

Comment: consider https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/how-to-start-web-mapping

Comment: thanks, I am trying to do it through my browser and apache