# How to create GIS like Uster?

Tags: qgis, geoserver, openlayers, geoext, qgis-web-client

I downloaded QGIS, GeoServer, OpenLayers, Ext, GeoExt, qgis-web-client and osgeo, and I have map shapefiles. I would like create a web site like [the Uster site](http://webgis.uster.ch/maps/av/grundplan_av?format=image/png;%20mode=8bit&visibleLayers=Abstandslinien,Nomenklatur,Fixpunkte,Geb%C3%A4ude,Grenzen,Einzelobjekte,Bodenbedeckung,Liegenschaften%20Fl%C3%A4che,Einzelobjekte%20Unterst%C3%A4nde,Einzelobjekte%20Unterirdische%20Geb%C3%A4ude&fullColorLayers=Orthofoto%202008&searchtables=&startExtent=692000,241500,700100,249000&maxExtent=692000,241500,700100,249000).

I need help, can you provide tutorial links?

Answer (score 6):

Go through the following questions.

1. [GIS for the web](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21452/gis-for-the-web)
2. [Steps to Start Web Mapping](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8113/steps-to-start-web-mapping)
3. [Web GIS Development Skill Sets](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/913/web-gis-development-skill-sets)

Answer (score 1):

This web map was created using:

QGIS - set up how you want your project to look

QGIS Server (sometimes called QGIS MapServer) - serve up your QGIS project

QGIS Web Client - browser-based access to your QGIS project

If you don't already have one, I would recommend setting up a Linux box first.  Linux Mint and Ubuntu work particularly well.  You'll also need to know a thing or two about the Apache HTTP Server.

Good luck.

Comment: Hi all i installed and view qgis web client. i just need search from my data

Comment: The installation guide describes how to perform a search against a PostGIS/PostgreSQL database.  https://github.com/qgis/qgis-web-client

Comment: i installed postgresql and imported shape file information by postgis. but don't match fields of searchtables

Comment: @Byambatsogt Tumurkhuu Better to ask this as a separate question after accepting one of the answers above.